# IDataErrorInfo indexer and array properties

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf

I have a custom class that implements the IDataErrorInfo interface and has several properties bound to textboxes in the UI. The `string this[string name]` indexer works just fine for regular int/string properties, but I can't seem to get it to work with string[] properties. For example binding

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding StringEntry, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="30" />
```

Works, but binding

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding StringList[0], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="30" />
```

will not. Same for an int[] property. It is not even triggering the indexer function call, at all. Is there a way to make it work with array properties or will I be forced to define a property for each array element?

**EDIT**: full class, since it appears I wasn't clear.

```
class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
   public MyObject()
   {
      stringEntry = "text";
      stringList = new string[] { "text1", "text2" };
   }

   private string[] stringList;
   public string[] StringList
   {
      get
      {
         return this.stringList;
      }
      set
      {
         if (this.stringList != value)
         {
            this.stringList = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("StringList");
         }
      }
   }

   private string stringEntry
   public string StringEntry
   {
      get
      {
         return this.stringEntry;
      }
      set
      {
         if (this.stringEntry != value)
         {
            this.stringEntry = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("StringEntry");
         }
      }
   }

   public override string Error
   {
      get
      {
         return null;
      }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
   {
      if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
      {
         this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
      }
   }

   public override string this[string name]
   {
      get
      {
         string result = null; // I have a breakpoint here, it's never triggered
                               // when I change the text in the StringList
                               // It DOES work for the StringEntry though.
         switch (name)
         {
            case "StringEntry":
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringEntry))
               {
                  result = "Entry cannot be emtpy";
               }
               break;
            case "StringList[0]": // doesn't work like this
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringList[0]))
               {
                  result = "Entry cannot be emtpy";
               }
               break;
            case "StringList": // nor like this
               if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringList[0]))
               {
                  result = "Entry cannot be emtpy";
               }
               break;
         }
         return result;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `StringList`? Where is the `this[int]` code?

Comment: @PatrickHofman as i wrote, StringList is a `string[]`, and there is no `this[int]` code. If you mean the `this[string name]` function, it's part of the `IDataErrorInfo` interface, so since my class implements it, it's within my class.

Comment: And how did you expect it calls that method if you didn't override it on the `StringList`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have no idea. That's why I'm here asking this question, obviously. I edited the full test class now, so maybe it's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

With the binding `Text="{Binding StringList[0],` it will always refer to the first indexed string of the `StringList` property and it won't call the indexer.

If you want to refer the indexer then try with `Text="{Binding [StringList[0]],` in this case `StringList[0]` will be considered as a key for the indexer and not the property itself.

**Edit:** **Updated**

```
    class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    public MyObject()
    {
        stringEntry = "text";
        stringList = new string[] { "text1", "text2" };
    }

    private string[] stringList;
    public string[] StringList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stringList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.stringList != value)
            {
                this.stringList = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("StringList");
            }
        }
    }

    private string stringEntry;
    public string StringEntry
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stringEntry;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.stringEntry != value)
            {
                this.stringEntry = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("StringEntry");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null; // I have a breakpoint here, it's never triggered
                                  // when I change the text in the StringList
                                  // It DOES work for the StringEntry though.
            switch (name)
            {
                case "StringEntry":
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringEntry))
                    {
                        result = "Entry cannot be emtpy";
                    }
                    break;
                case "[(0)]": // works like this, this block is updated
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringList[0]))
                    {
                        result = "Entry cannot be emtpy";
                    }
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringList[1]))
                    {
                        result = "Entry cannot be emtpy";
                    }
                    break;
                case "StringList": // not required
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringList[0]))
                    {
                        result = "Entry cannot be emtpy";
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public string this[int index]
    {
        get { return StringList[index]; }
        set
        {
            StringList[index] = value;
        }
    }
}


        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=[(sys:Int32)0], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5"/>
```

Here we have implemented a wrapper for `StringList` array which will notify on indexed value change, which will fire your validation indexer code.

Comment: Doing this forces me to change the binding to OneWay though, else I'm getting an `InvalidOperationException: TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding do not work for read-only property`. I do need it to be TwoWay,  however.

Comment: For indexed binding it won't call the indexer automatically as your class property is not being changed. Here on change of your array values, you will have to `this.NotifyPropertyChanged("StringList")` so that your indexer gets called for `StringList` property and there you can check the indexed values and provide the appropriate error message

Comment: Thanks, this seems so close to what I need. Alas, it either says `Error creating Path from text "[(sys:Int32)0]"`, or if I omit the `Path` part, it's back to "TwoWay not allowed". The `DataContext` is set to the object of the MyObject class. Also, how would I go about it if there are more than one string[] properties in the class?

Comment: Have you added a reference for `sys`? you will have to add a reference in `xaml` like  `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

Comment: Oh. Yes, sorry, still kind of a beginner. After adding that, the int indexer works (gets/sets value from index 0 and 1). The string indexer, doesn't, though (name is `[(0)]` for both index 0 and 1). I have `Text="{Binding Path=[(sys:Int32)0]` for one textbox and `Text="{Binding Path=[(sys:Int32)1]` for another.

Comment: For that you can validate both the indexed values on same case, it would work. check the updated code.

Comment: Yes, but it also marks the first text box as invalid (upon changing its value) even though only the second is, for example. I don't quite understand how this works, I expected the second textbox to trigger the indexer with `name="[(1)]"`. I also can't seem to figure out how to make this work with multiple string[] properties...

Comment: Try this, it should work. I tested it and it was marking only respective textboxes as invalid, not both.

Comment: I did, if you change box 0 to invalid -> box 0 is marked as invalid and box 1 is not - so far so good. Now change box 1 to something valid -> box 1 will be marked as invalid because box 0 fails the check. Now fix box 0 -> box 1 is still marked as invalid despite having a valid value. That's really confusing for the user.